# Run video in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, video

I want my first project to be implemented in the form of a video, how do I do this?
I want to play a video and then when I click on the form, video get stopped and app go to another page.
please help me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try using MediaElement

```
<MediaElement Name="VideoControl" 
              Source="C:\my.wmv" >    
</MediaElement>
```

Comment: You are my livesaver :)

Answer (score 4):

Using `MediaElement` control you will can play a video in WFP.
XAML code:

```
<MediaElement Name="VideoControl" Width="200" Height ="400"
                  Source="your_path_to_video_file.wmv" >    
</MediaElement>
```

It plays MPG files, too: `Source="C:\TestV.MPG"`

To know how to control it using Play, Stop, Pause buttons click [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/VideoWPF04082007164613PM/VideoWPF.aspx). It's a good article about this with many examples.

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple just use the MediaElement control in wpf to display your video on your form

[Simple WPF Media Player](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20478/A-simple-WPF-media-player-with-media-item-list)