# How to run ffmpeg from WPF?

Tags: wpf

I want to cut videos and add background music using timestamps using FFmpeg in my WPF app.

My app is totally basic.

I have a button to select file And field for timestamps

I am able to cut videos using cmd. But how can I do that in WPF?

Comment: Just issue a `Process.Start` with the apropriate parameters to run the external exe, just like any other external program.

Comment: ok..So there is no default support for that like UWP? is there a better alternative??

Comment: FFmpeg is a command line program. The correct (and pretty much only) way to run it is to issue the proper command line, be it from the command prompt or though C# code. UWP is even more limited here.

Comment: is there a better alternative of FFmpeg for WPF??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run video in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967539/run-video-in-wpf)

Comment: No, I do not just want to run the video I also want to cut and add background music to the video..